# I want to update the product list on the basis of search query. My treatment card is working fine but not essentials and medical

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have 4 categories `anmial` , `treatment`, `dailyEssentials` and `medical-care`

On the left side there are 3 cards for `treatment`, `dailyEssentials` and `medical-care` and one drop-down to select by `animals`.

the product gets updated perfectly for the `Animal` and the `treatment` category but `dailyEssentials` and `medical-care` are not giving required products as a output instead of that it's shows all the products.

URL - `http://localhost:3000/search/essential/6451eafc000f972917fe38fe`

- `6451eafc000f972917fe38fe` is dailyessential category id .

I have a question that the `treatment` card is very similar to `dailyEssentials` and `medical-care`
In my case `treatment` is working fine then why not `dailyEssentials` and `medical-care`.

This is the backend

```
exports.showAllProducts = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      // enable search
      const keyword = req.query.keyword
        ? {
            name: {
              $regex: req.query.keyword,
              $options: 'i',
            },
          }
        : {};
  
      // enable filter by animal
      const animalId = req.query.animal;
      const animalFilter = animalId ? { animal: animalId } : {};
  
      // enable filter by treatment
      const treatmentId = req.query.treatment;
      const treatmentFilter = treatmentId ? { treatment: treatmentId } : {};
  
      //enable filter by essentials
      const essentialId = req.query.dailyEssential;
      const essentialFilter = essentialId ? {dailyEssential: essentialId}: {};

      //enable filter by medical care
      const medicalCareId = req.query.medicalCare;
      const medicalCareFilter =  medicalCareId ? {medicalCare: medicalCareId}:{};

      // enable pagination
      const pageSize = 4;
      const page = Number(req.query.pageNumber) || 1;
  
   // construct the filter based on the keyword and any additional filters
   const filter = {
    ...keyword,
    ...animalFilter,
    ...treatmentFilter,
    ...essentialFilter,
    ...medicalCareFilter,
  };
      const count = await Product.find(filter).countDocuments();
      const products = await Product.find(filter)
        .skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
        .limit(pageSize);
  
      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        count,
        products,
        page,
        pages: Math.ceil(count / pageSize),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  });
```

ESSENTIAL_ACTION

```
import { DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_FAIL, DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_REQUEST, DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_RESET, DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_SUCCESS } from "../../constants/categories/dailyEssentialsConstants";
import axios from 'axios'


export const dailyEssentialsTypeLoadAction = () => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_REQUEST });
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/v1/essential');
        dispatch({
            type: DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_FAIL,
            payload: error.response.data.error
        });
    }
}
```

ESSENTIAL REDUCER

```
import { DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_FAIL, DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_REQUEST, DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_RESET, DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_SUCCESS } from "../../constants/categories/dailyEssentialsConstants";

export const loadDailyEssentialTypeReducer =  (state = {dailyEssentialType:[] },action)=>{
    switch (action.type){
        case DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_REQUEST:
            return { loading : true}
        case DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                dailyEssentialType: action.payload.essentialT
            }
        case DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_FAIL:
            return {
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload
            }
        case DAILY_ESSENTIALS_TYPE_LOAD_RESET:
            return {}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './product.css';
import { Box, Card, CardContent, Stack, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getProduct } from '../../actions/productAction';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Pagination from '@mui/material/Pagination';
import Loader from '../layout/Loader/Loader';
import SelectComponent from './SelectComponent';
import { animalTypeLoadAction } from '../../actions/categories/animalTypeAction';
import { treatmentTypeLoadAction } from '../../actions/categories/treatmentTypeAction';
import { dailyEssentialsTypeLoadAction } from '../../actions/categories/dailyEssentialTypeAction';
import { medicalCareTypeLoadAction } from '../../actions/categories/medicalCareTypeAction';


  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {error,loading,products,pages} = useSelector(state=>state.products)

  const { keyword,treatment,essential,medical} = useParams()
  const { treatmentType } = useSelector(state => state.treatmentTypeAll)
  const { dailyEssentialType } = useSelector(state => enter image description herestate.dailyEssentialTypeAll)
  const { MedicalCareType } = useSelector(state => state.medicalCareTypeAll)

  const [page, setPage ] = useState(1);
  const [animal, setAnimal ] = useState();

  useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(getProduct(page,keyword,animal,treatment,essential,medical))
  },[dispatch,page,keyword,animal,treatment,essential,medical])

useEffect(()=>{
  dispatch(animalTypeLoadAction())
  dispatch(treatmentTypeLoadAction())
  dispatch(dailyEssentialsTypeLoadAction())
  dispatch(medicalCareTypeLoadAction())

},[])

  const handleChangeCategory=(e)=>{
      setAnimal(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {
        loading ? <Loader /> : <>
     <Box sx={{ bgcolor: '#fff', minHeight: '100vh' }}>
        <Stack direction={{ xs: 'column', sm: 'row' }} spacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 4 }}>
          <Box sx={{ flex: 2, p: 2 }}>
            <Card sx={{ minWidth: 170, mb: 3, mt: 3, p: 2 }}>
              <Box sx={{ pb: 2 }}>
                <Typography component="h4" sx={{ color: '#217c04', fontWeight: 700, fontFamily: 'Inter' }}>
                  SORT AS PER YOUR PREFERENCE
                </Typography>
              </Box>
              <SelectComponent handleChangeCategory={handleChangeCategory} animal={animal} /> 
            </Card>
                   {/* treatment category  card*/}
          <Card sx={{ minWidth: 150, mb: 3,mt:2, p: 2 }}>
          <Box sx={{ pb: 2 }}>
              <Typography component="h4" sx={{ color: '#217c04', fontWeight: 600 }}>
                        SORT BY TREATMENT
              </Typography>
              {
              treatmentType && treatmentType.map((treatment) => (
                <Link className='link' to={`/search/treatment/${treatment._id.toString()}`} key={treatment._id}>
              <Card sx={{ minWidth: 150, mb: 1,mt:1, p: 1}}>
              <CardContent>
              <Typography variant="h6" color="text.primary">
                        {treatment.TreatmentTypeName}
              </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
            </Link>
              ))
            }
        </Box>
        </Card>

            {/* daily-Essential-Card */}
            <Card sx={{ minWidth: 150, mb: 3,mt:2, p: 2 }}>
          <Box sx={{ pb: 2 }}>
              <Typography component="h4" sx={{ color: '#217c04', fontWeight: 600 }}>
                        OUR DAILY ESSENTIALS
              </Typography>
              {
              dailyEssentialType && dailyEssentialType.map((essential) => (
                <Link className='link' to={`/search/essential/${essential._id.toString()}`} key={essential._id}>
              <Card sx={{ minWidth: 150, mb: 1,mt:1, p: 1}}>
              <CardContent>
              <Typography variant="h6" color="text.primary">
                        {essential.essentialName}
              </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
            </Link>
              ))
            }
        </Box>
        </Card>


        {/* medical-care-card */}
        <Card sx={{ minWidth: 150, mb: 3,mt:2, p: 2 }}>
          <Box sx={{ pb: 2 }}>
              <Typography component="h4" sx={{ color: '#217c04', fontWeight: 600 }}>
                        SORT BY Medical
              </Typography>
              {
              MedicalCareType && MedicalCareType.map((medical) => (
                 <Link className='link' to={`/search/medical/${medical._id.toString()}`} key={medical._id}>
              <Card sx={{ minWidth: 150, mb: 1,mt:1, p: 1}}>
              <CardContent>
              <Typography variant="h6" color="text.primary">
                        {medical.medicalCareName}
              </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
           </Link>
              ))
            }
        </Box>
        </Card>
  </Box>

       
          {/* main card */}
          
          {
            products && products.length === 0 ? <>
                    <Box
                       sx={{
                        minHeight: '350px',
                        display: 'flex',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center'
                      }}>

                        <h2>No result found!</h2>
                    </Box>
            </> :
            <>
            <div className='product-main-container' style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
           <Box sx={{ flex: 6, p: 1,mt:4 }}>
           <Box sx={{ minHeight: '350px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',flexDirection: 'column' }}>
              {products.map((product) => (
                <ProductCard key={product._id} product={product} />
              ))}
            </Box>
            <Stack spacing={2} >
            <Pagination variant='outlined' className='pagination' page={page} count={pages === 0 ? 1 : pages} onChange={(event, value) => setPage(value)} />
          </Stack>
          </Box>
          </div>
            </>
          }
        </Stack>
      </Box>
        </>
      }
     
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/user/Login';
import Product from './components/product/Product';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
        <Route path='/products' element={<Product />} />

        {/* product categories routes */}
        <Route path='/search/treatment/:treatment' element={<Product />} />
        <Route path='/search/essential/:essential' element={<Product />} />
        <Route path='/search/medical/:medical' element={<Product />} />

        </Routes>
    </Router>
       
      
 

    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

productAction.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
    ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
    ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
    ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
    CLEAR_ERRORS
} from "../constants/productConstants"


export const getProduct = (pageNumber,keyword='',animal='',treatment='',essential='',medical='') => async (dispatch)=>
{
    try{
        dispatch({type:ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST})

        //let link = `/api/v1/products`;
        let link = `/api/v1/products/?pageNumber=${pageNumber}&keyword=${keyword}&animal=${animal}&treatment=${treatment}&essential=${essential}&medical=${medical}`;

        const {data} =  await axios.get(link)
        dispatch({
            type:ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
            payload:data,
        })

    }
    catch(error){
        dispatch({
            type: ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
            payload:error.response.data.message,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an issue with the `Product` component? It's not updating when the path changes? Can you [edit] the post to include all relevant code you are working with in your [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry, just realized the first snippet is the `Product` component code, it's just missing the function declaration. I see it's using the `useParams` hook to access the path parameters and there's a `useEffect` hook with those params as dependencies. What exactly is the issue or problem? Is it only the `"/search/essential/:essential"` route that isn't working? Is the `/api/v1/products/` endpoint in the `getProduct ` thunk returning the data you expect?

Comment: `/search/essential/:essential` route and `/search/medical/:medical` route is not updating the products. rest all things are working fine. and thunk is returning the data as data is visible in the state. The `/search/treatment/:treatment` is working fine @DrewReese

Comment: Is the `getProduct` action dispatched when you expect it to, i.e. when the route path param changes, or any of the dependencies really? Let's start there. If that's working, then the next thing to check is the `getProduct` action. Is the endpoint hit with the correct expected params? Is the correct data returned? If so, then we need to see the reducers to see how state updates are processed.

Comment: ya It's showing all the products and in getProductAction.js I have `console.log(essential)` it's showing result

Comment: Ok, so if the `getProduct` dispatch and action fetch the correct result data when the route changes please include the reducer function(s) in your post so we can see how state is updated.

Comment: it's showing result when the route params changes the products get updated for `/search/treatment/:treatment` card but not for the `/search/essential/:essential` I want to update the product in the same manner. Instead of updated products it's showing all the products.

Comment: `console.log(essential)` when I consoled it's showing essentialid

Comment: Ok, so am I just misunderstanding something then? You said the action was dispatched and the API request made and the expected data was returned. Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "it's showing all the products"? Are you saying your endpoint ***doesn't*** return the correct data for the queryParams passed to it? Are you saying you need to fetch ***different*** data entirely, based on the active route path?

Comment: You are rendering `Product` on 4 different routes.... it needs to handle all those different use cases then.

Comment: I mean when I click on the card it's showing all the products list. I want updated data on the basis of card I choose. It's not showing the correct data for the queryParams.

Comment: yes I am rendering product on 4 different routes

Comment: So I guess we're back to asking that when the route changes is the `getProduct` action dispatched with the values you expect? If so, check the `getProduct` action calls the endpoint with the queryParams you expect? If so then is the response value what you expect? If so is the reducer updating state as you expect? It sounds like you've said you are seeing the expected `essential` value in the action... so I'm thinking either your API isn't working correctly, or you are not updating the products state correctly.

Comment: `/search/treatment/:treatment ` is giving expected output but not `/search/essential/:essential` -- the url gets change in the browser but I am not getting expected output

Comment: API is working fine in the postman

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: Dunno, like I said, if the code is all correct then the issue is the endpoint or something with how the products state is updated. You still haven't included that code though. Is the `Product` component supposed to call a ***different*** API endpoint on the other routes? If so, then why the first API that takes all those query params? Something's not adding up here.

Comment: productAction Route `/api/v1/products/?pageNumber=${pageNumber}&keyword=${keyword}&animal=${animal}&treatment=${treatment}&essential=${essential}&medical=${medical}`                   essential route--- `/api/v1/essential`

Comment: Well I guess that confirms the problem.... the code needs to hit a different endpoint. What should the `Product` component do when on the `"/products"` path, dispatch no action to hit any backend API?

Comment: what I have to do ? why it's working fine in the case of treatment but not essentials. As both are very similar

Comment: Dunno, I didn't create your APIs. Do you have *different* actions & state/reducers that need to be dispatched and updated for the other "categories", e.g. an essentials state/reducers/actions set, a medical state/reducers/actions set, and similarly for treatment? If so, can you add these to your [mcve]? And how do these all get selected for the UI?

Comment: yes, I have different actions & state/reducers that need to be dispatched and updated for the other "categories"

Answer (score 1):

So It was my mistake the error was in ProductAction.js

the link would be
`/api/v1/products/?pageNumber=${pageNumber}&keyword=${keyword}&animal=${animal}&treatment=${treatment}&dailyEssential=${dailyEssential}`

Instead of `essentials` I should have use `dailyEssential`

- same for medical Instead of `medical` I should have use `medicalCare`

Answer (score 0):

You should conditionally select which action to dispatch to call the correct/expected backend API. Giving each route a "category" prop to pass to `Product` will make selecting the correct endpoint easier.

Example:

```
<Route path='/products' element={<Product />} /> // all products? ‍♂️
<Route
  path='/search/treatment/:id'
  element={<Product category="treatment" />}
/>
<Route
  path='/search/essential/:id'
  element={<Product category="essential" />}
/>
<Route
  path='/search/medical/:id'
  element={<Product category="medical" />}
/>
```

```js
const Product = ({ category }) => {
  const { id, keyword } = useParams(); // I don't see where keyword is defined ‍♂️

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    switch(category) {
      case "treatment":
        dispatch(getTreatment(page, id));
        break;

      case "essential":
        dispatch(getEssential(page, id));
        break;

      case "medical":
        dispatch(getMedical(page, id));
        break;

      default:
        dispatch(getProduct(page, keyword, id));
    }
  }, [category, dispatch, page, keyword, id]);

  ...
}
```

From here each action should fetch its expected data from its respective API and update the appropriate state, either the `products` state or its own state that would also need to be selected in the `Product` component to be rendered.

Comment: I have added the essentialAction.js in my question. This is not working the keyword is for search functionalities. I will implement it later.

Comment: @AnjaliTejasvi Can you be more specific about what exactly isn't working? I see the `dailyEssentialsTypeLoadAction` doesn't take any essential param value... is it not coupled to the URL path the app is matching on? Can you update your post to explain what the UI should be doing for these 4 routes? In other words, what the expected user experience (UX) should be?

Comment: can I add gitHub link?

Comment: @AnjaliTejasvi All relevant code should really be as self-contained in the post as possible, but links out to external resources are acceptable as supplementary information.